# angularjs - ng-repeat being called before scope variable is defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a `md-tabs` setup, I have it binded to `$scope.selectedIndex` so that I can change it by code when I need to.

I use a button, call my function that updates data, I then change `$scope.selectedIndex` to the tab number needed (In this case 3) that will then change the selected tab.

All of that is fine, except it's calling `$scope.selectedIndex` before `.forEach()` call is finished, which results in a `ng-repeat` not working as it exits silently with no errors since its not defined.

Button Calls:
`ng-click="initTVShow(show)"`

Function:

```
$scope.initTVShow = function(show) {
  var rng = "";
  var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
  for( var i=0; i < 10; i++ )
    rng += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

  $scope.show = show;
  $scope.show_name = show.title.split(' ').join('') + "-" + rng;
  $scope.poster = show.images.poster;
  $scope.backdrop = show.images.poster;
  $scope.seasons = [{},{}];

  getShow(show.imdb_id, function (err, show) {
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      $scope.seasons[i] = show.episodes.filter((episode) => episode.season === i);
    }
  });
  $scope.selectedIndex=3;
};
```

As you can see, `$scope.selectedIndex=3;` basically changes to Tab #4 (0-based).

Then the following ng-repeat does not seem to work and most likely because .forEach hasn't finished yet. I tested with $scope.seasons with 2 empty index's to test and that works.

`<span ng-repeat="season in seasons">{{season.number}}</span>`

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is because the function getShow retrieves data asynchronously. Show it to us.
Try this:

```
getShow(show.imdb_id, function (err, show) {
  show.episodes.forEach(function(array){
    $scope.seasons[array.season] = array;
    });
    $scope.selectedIndex=3;
});
```

Comment: That also doesnt work, with this it wont change at all for some reason

Comment: If setting the selected index inside the callback isn't working, I would warrant your callback never gets called. Are you able to verify that the server is returning data and that the callback is firing? (Via a console log or debugging statement?)

Answer (score 1):

It's because the data not ready and the DOM is.
you can solve it easily by adding `ng-if` on the element and check if the data ready.

Like:`<span ng-if="season.number" ng-repeat="season in seasons">{{season.number}}</span>`

Comment: I see what your trying to do, but that actually doesnt work - It seems to hide it and im guessing never showing it when the data is actually there

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, it was actually just caused by the for() loop *(Which pre-edit, was a .forEach)*, I simple added a callback to it, which changed the tab and it just WORKED!

Changed:
`for (let i = 0; i < 11; i++) { }`

To:
`for (let i = 0; i < 11 || function(){ $scope.selectedIndex=3; }(); i++) { }`